Clicking a hyperlink in a pdf triggers logout
I open a pdf file with my browser (firefox, chromium).
Then I press a hyperlink to a website on which I was logged on using a cookie.
The request is sent without a cookie, so the web server sets a new cookie, and then the current cookie gets replaced by the new one. So the previous session gets abandoned, and I have to login again.
Is this a bug?


Is this a bug?

For your case, why is any url other than "https://base.example.domain/context-path/some-other-path/logout" and "https://base.example.domain/context-path/some-other-path/login" allowed to update auth cookies?
In my opinion, its definitely a bug.
